# nginx rewrite rule to overwrite $uri as well

Tags: nginx, rewrite, fastcgi

I have an URL like `^/d/something/(.*)$`, what I want to do is rewrite it internally, with no permanent or temporary HTTP redirect, so that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will have just `$1` and not the whole `^/d/something/(.*)$`. Using nginx.

Here is what I tried:

```
location /d/something/ {
  rewrite "^/d/something/(.*)$" /$1 last;
}

location / {
    include php-fcgi.conf;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
}
```

in the `php-fcgi.conf` there is `fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;` and `$request_uri` remains the same, so when I hit `/d/something/something2` symfony reouter, which relies on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` shows `/d/something/something2` while I expect it to be just `/something2`. I assume that's because `$request_uri` is not changed.

If I replace it with `fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $uri;` then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` becomes `/` , no matter what I send in `something2` part, it's always just `/`. Why is that happening and how can I internally rewrite it to `/$1`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: here are the contents of `php-fcgi.conf`:

```
location ~ \.php {
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
}
```

Comment: What does `php-fcgi.conf` contain?

Comment: @RichardSmith : updated my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect `$uri` to have the value `/index.php` by the time the request is passed to the PHP script, so I don't understand why you are seeing `/`. However...

The simplest solution would be to execute the PHP script from within the `location` where the URI is rewritten. This is achieved using a `rewrite...break` and overwriting the REQUEST_URI and SCRIPT_FILENAME parameters.

For example:

```
location /d/something/ {
    rewrite "^/d/something/(.*)$" /$1 break;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI      $uri;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
}
```

Place the `fastcgi_param` statements **after** the `include` statement.

---

Alternatively, use a *regular expression* `location` block. Note that the order of *regular expression* `location` blocks is significant. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/d/something(/.*)$ {
    try_files /index.php =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI  $1;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard! I just tested the first approach and it worked. I think the main problem with my attempts were that I modified `REQUEST_URI`, I should have replaced `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and use `break` , but then pointing it to php-fcgi as it will never reach the second pass. Thanks again!